# Does CSRF exist in pure rest api without UI?

Tags: rest, csrf

I don't know much about CSRF, but after reading the doc, it seems it only happens in browser. So now I have a library with rest api, but no ui. Do I need to take care of CSRF in this rest api ? Thanks

Comment: Please let me know if my answer was useful for you. If it answers your question, please consider accepting it

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's important to note that CSRF is an attack that can be exploited in browers.

According to [Guidelines for Implementation of REST](http://www.nsa.gov/ia/_files/support/guidelines_implementation_rest.pdf), a document issued by NSA, REST APIs are vulnerable to CSRF attacks:

> **F. Cross Site Request Forgery:**
>
> Cross site request forgery (CSRF) attacks attempt to force an authenticated user to
>   execute functionality without their knowledge. [...]
>
> It is important to note that CSRF attacks execute functionality, but are unable to
>   interact with the response from the targeted server. [...]
>
> REST is stateless at its core and thus inherently vulnerable to CSRF attacks. [...]

Two approaches are suggested to ensure protection. Summarizing them below:

### Custom HTTP header

The first method involves checking the presence of a custom header (agreed-upon between the server and a client – e.g. `X-CSRF` or `X-Requested-By`) in all state-changing requests coming from the client. The value of the header does not really matter. It works, because the browser would not send custom headers unless the web page makes a request using XMLHttpRequest, which only allows requests to the same site.

[This method is currently used by Jersey](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-server/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/filter/CsrfProtectionFilter.java), the JAX-RS reference implementation for REST web services in Java.

And it's also mentioned in [Robust Defenses for Cross-Site Request Forgery](http://seclab.stanford.edu/websec/csrf/csrf.pdf) from Stanford University.

### CSRF tokens

The second method involves protecting REST endpoints against CSRF attacks by establishing session state. This approach **violates REST principles** and involves the use of a CSRF token that is generated for each action, then associated with the user session and submitted with each important website action.

This essentially forces a sequential ordering of actions on the application.

Comment: *Guidelines for Implementation of REST* is mirrored [here](https://johnjamesjacoby.files.wordpress.com/2015/11/guidelines_implementation_rest.pdf).

Comment: Thanks, as my understanding, CSRF only happens when browser add some cookies, so if my rest library won't be used in browser, does it mean I have no CSRF issue ?

Comment: @zjffdu CSRF is an attack that can be exploited in *browers*. CSRF is not likely within a mobile application. Android and iOS have security controls so that apps can't read other app's data.

Comment: What if I've secured my cookie-based authentication (browser) with CSRF, and now want to allow non-browser requests to the same endpoints?